# PHP based Printable version

Tags: php, css

I have a handcoded site with a few hundred articles. My current theme follows a blue background. Of course the images are therefore, with a blue background. For future support of printable versions, I have (from first day) kept two versions of the images with the latter one having a white background. These ones has '_print' before their extensions.

Of course, the best way to create a printable version is to use a different CSS and hide headers and sidebars by 'display:none' in respective CSS.

Is there any way I can use PHP to automatically add '_print' before '.jpg' in printable versions? Or is there is any other way altogether?

Comment: What kinds of images are they - maybe you can make them transparent PNGs, making it unnecessary to keep two versions? It may not be possible if you need the JPG format's superior photo compression capabilities, though

Comment: Do you already have a page for each article which is for printable, or is this the next task..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do this either with PHP or with Javascript.

in PHP you could just pass a parameter like ?print=true and then write a little helper function to get the appropriate image url.

```
<?php
function getImageUrl(imageUrl) { 
   if(isset($_GET["print"])) {
      return preg_replace('\.jpg$','_print\.jpg',imageUrl);
   }
   return imageUrl;
}
?>
```

Disclaimer - not a PHP dev.

Answer (score 2):

If the php script uses the full name of the images while it is building the website, why not?

You should create something like this, if I expect your code to be like this:

```
echo '<img src="images/artcle_'.$aid.',jpg"/>';
```

You should add a new variable via $_GET or $_POST, e.g.:

```
$print = "";

if($_GET['print'] == "1"){
     $print = "_print";
}
```

And later:

```
echo '<img src="images/artcle_'.$aid.$print.',jpg"/>';
```

Resulting in the print versions only being displayed if the Print param is sent.

Answer (score 1):

```
<? php if ($print_page == true)
{
    $append = "_print";
}
else
{
    $append = "";
} ?>


<html>
  <body>
     <img src = "/image/image<?php echo $append?>.jpg />
  </body>
</html>
```

by including $append in all your image links -they will auto update with the _print if required. Just set $print_page as true or false as needed if you want the page to be printable